# Indenting in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to indent blocks of code in vim instead of going to each line and indenting a line at a time?

Maybe highlight the code and execute a command that will indent the highlighted code?

Comment: n >> (where n is the number of lines you want to indent), if you want to auto indent, n == would work

Comment: Is there a way to set how many spaces `>>` will indent?

Comment: set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 would set it for you as you have seen I have set it to 2 you can add that to your ~/.vimrc file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for indenting there's both the `>` command, which simply shifts to the right by adding one level of indent (how much is determined by the `'shiftwidth'` option, and `'expandtab'` tells whether to use Tabs or spaces), and the `=` command, which applies (language-specific) indentation rules.

Both commands work on line(s) when doubling, i.e. `>>` / `==`; you address multiple lines by prepending a number.

But they also take a `{motion}`, e.g. `3j` (3 lines down), or `}` (to the end of the paragraph).

And finally, you can make a visual selection (`V`), make it the right size, and then apply the command to it.

Answer (score 1):

hilite      code and type `>`